Many-to-many relationship with composite keys but without a join table in Spring Data JPA
Let's say I have these two simplified entities in a read-only database I cannot change the schema of:
Article                            Attribute
------------                       -------------
art_nr: int                        art_nr: int
country: varchar                   attribute_id: int
...                                rank: int
Primary key: (art_nr, country)     ...
                                   Primary key: (art_nr, attribute_id, rank)

I want to have a list of Attributes eagerly fetched into a property of the Article entity in order to avoid the n+1 query problem. The join column is obviously just art_nr.
However, I can't seem to model this relationship in Spring Data or Hibernate.
The ManyToMany relationship type does not work without a join column and modelling this with OneToMany doesn't work as the join columns can't uniquely identify the corresponding entity.
What are my options?

I don't think JPA provides for modeling your (article, attribute) association as a mapped relationship.  All of these identify each mapped end of such a relationship by a full primary key.  If "read-only database" still permits you to add a new view, then you should be able to create a join table as a view.  If you can't do even that with the DB then I don't think you're going to get all the way to where you want to be.

FWIW, I think there is an underlying data modeling problem here, in that there is an implicit entity -- a country-less article -- that does not have a table of its own.  From an E/R perspective, the association you're looking at is not direct.  Rather, it goes through that implicit entity.

@JohnBollinger Even though I did not design this schema, when I really think about it, I can't say I can pinpoint an actual fault in the modelling. In other words, why would we need a join table? I also feel like this type of join is very common. It's just that we don't model it explicitly.

You can join your two tables just fine in SQL.  That was never my point.  The modeling problem is what I already said, which I can re-express as the schema not mapping cleanly onto an E/R model.  That's not necessarily a crippling issue in general, but it does get in the way of mapping your persistence unit with JPA, because that's exactly an exercise in E/R modeling.

I see your point. And you're right, a country-less article does indeed exist explicitly (in other databases via DB-link). I'm just struggling to find a way to emulate a FETCH JOIN without having to explicitly model this relationship. Theoretically, the query result would look exactly like as if it had a join table so I see no reason why Spring Data wouldn't be able to connect the right entities together.

You need to add @JoinColumn.
Something like that:
class Article {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="art_nr", referencedColumnName="art_nr")
    List<Attribute> attributes;

}

If it doesn't work for you try @JoinFormula.

I've already tried this. I'll get an error saying "referenced column(s) don't refer to a single property"'

You need to add property or refer to existing in composite id.

art_nr is already a property and a part of a composite ID in Attribute

I got it. It mapped as List? You need to use JoinFormula then.

Yep mapped as list. I find JoinFormula a bit confusing though. The Javadoc says it has to be valid SQL, yet the latest Hibernate 6 docs have no mention of SQL and instead use something else. How would I go about simulating a FETCH JOIN with JoinFormula, since apparently it's not picked up in JPQL?

After trying JoinFormula with a simple SQL query, I get the error that the foreign key referring Article from Attribute has the wrong number of columns (should include all FK columns), which is exactly what I don't want.
